# How could the Russian government (legally) send Griner to prison even if she is acquitted?

Tags: criminal-law, drugs, russia

[According to the BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/world-us-canada-62049164)

> Ms Griner has been held in Russia since her 17 February arrest at Moscow's Sheremetyevo airport after cannabis oil was allegedly found in her luggage.
>
> She is currently on trial and if convicted could face up to ten years in prison.
>
> Fewer than 1% of defendants in criminal cases are acquitted in Russia.
>
> However unlike in US courts, even if [Griner] is acquitted, Russia's government has the authority to overturn any decision and send her to prison.

I'm rather confused about that last sentence. What law would allow the Russian government to overrule the court in a case like this?

Comment: The law of "might makes right".  Russia is a *de facto* dictatorship, not a country based around the rule of law.

Comment: @Mark: yeah, sure, but it seems it's even "legal dictatorship" in this case. Unless the BBC is embelishing it.

Comment: When you look at it closely, the US government also claims sweeping powers to detain foreigners without trial or sentence. The difference is that basketball players get more sympathy than islamist terrorists.